# Is graphics card to monitor unidirectional?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, vga

I recently bought GTX 1050 graphics card. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a VGA port and my monitor (being very old) only supports VGA.

While looking through adapters, I found one at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.in/Terabyte-Hdmi-Converter-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00S0C76GQ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1486444128&sr=8-3&keywords=hdmi%20vga) which I think should do the job. But the description says:

> THIS IS A UNIDIRECTIONAL DEVICE, IT WORKS FROM HDMI TO VGA, NOT IN REVERSE. IT MEANS YOUR SOURCE SHOULD BE HDMI AND DESTINATION SHOULD BE VGA.

In my case, I'm assuming that the GTX 1050 would be the source and the monitor would be the destination. Am I right in my assumption or is it the other way around?

Comment: You right, it HDMI-to-VGA only adapter. Adapters (or to be correct converters) that do opposite VGA-to-HDMI cost at least 10 times more

Comment: So I won't be able to use it in my case?

Comment: No, if your video card has HDMI socket and your monitor accepts only VGA then adapter you listed in  your question will work without problem

Comment: The video signal goes in one direction only.  There is EDID information that goes back from the monitor to video card, to tell the computer what resolution and refresh rates the monitor can accept, but if that's blocked by the adapter it's just an inconvenience, not particularly difficult to pick the right video modes by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unidirectional by definition means "one direction". In your case, the direction you want is going from the HDMI in the PC to the VGA on the monitor, and the listing clearly states that this is the one direction it goes:

> 1. Connect the HDMI connector of the adapter to your HDMI device
> 2. Connect the VGA Cable
>      of your monitor or projector to the VGA Female port of the adapter

So, short answer. Yes! This is what you need and should work for you just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. For the sake of knowledge, what will be the reverse of it? Motherboard VGA to TV HDMI?

Comment: Correct. Something like this https://www.amazon.com/Tendak-Output-Converter-Adapter-Desktop/dp/B00MJ6IWT4